# Polymer: ERROR no ports available start_server.js

Tags: server, centos, polymer, ports

can anybody help me with my issue when i do polymer serve -H [77.68.84.107] it brings up an error saying no ports available? im really stuck on this.

i am running a 1&1 cloud server with centOS 7

Comment: Did you run it with sufficient rights to bind to a port?
Try `sudo ...`

Comment: i have just tried # sudo polymer serve -H [77.68.84.107] and it has come up again with the same error which is Error: Error: no available ports. ports tired [loads of ports] at /user/lib/node_modules/polymer-cli/node_modules/polyserve/lib/start_server.js:84:19

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had this problem.

I changed `--hostname` value to the ip instead of the domain name or localhost

if you are doing it on your machine put 127.0.0.1 `instead` of `localhost`.